# lib version and directory

Tags: r, bash, gcc, command-line-interface

I try to call this:

```
iMac-O:AppDirectory ME$ Rscript -e 'shiny:runApp( launch.browser=TRUE)'
```

Answer:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.8.3/libgfortran.3.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

In dir `lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/`.

there is version "4.9.1" not "4.8.3". What could I do to do the "right call"?

Comment: You [apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161100/run-shellscript-from-mac-automator) solved this. Please post an answer and accept it so that others can benefit and learn, and so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved.

Comment: #resolved
find two different libs. delete one of them. everything works fine.

Comment: Post a proper answer. Accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I also had a very similar issue.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/4.9/libgfortran.3.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.3/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I believe it is related to my gcc having been installed by homebrew. What worked for me:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/
```